# MFCCs are useful for speech & music analysis. For music, why isn't the 12-tone scale used instead of the mel scale?

Tags: mfcc, music, feature-extraction

As far as I understand, the mel scale was developed empirically using something akin to "just noticeable differences" in a subject's perception of frequencies. The scale ends up being a log transformation of the frequency-amplitude space, which stretches and pulls the space so that "just noticeable differences" are the same throughout. More specifically, the mel scale has the form $2595\cdot \log_{10}(1+\frac{f}{700})$, where $f$ is the frequency.

I can see the mel scale being very applicable to speech analysis. We want the feature extraction to focus on tiny perceivable differences. These differences are likely the drivers of our actual cognitive processing of speech, so using a scale that reflects that seems like the way to go.

However, if we are analyzing a piano recording, the sounds are all inside the 12-note system. Who cares about tiny perceivable differences in the sound? When listening to or creating music, the focus is (usually) on which actual tone (or set of tones) is being produced -- where each tone is one of the 12 in the Western system.

Hence, just like we use the mel scale to "calibrate" our analysis to the differences in sound that are important to speech and human hearing (and "throwing out" what's not important), shouldn't we use the 12-tone scale when analyzing music to similarly "optimize" our analysis? Or would we throw too much away?

I have not seen a discussion about this in applications of MFCC to music. Maybe it's because there is no issue. But maybe our analyses would become "better" or "more intuitive" if, when applying MFCCs to music, we used the 12-tone scale instead of the mel scale.